# Comparing two date as string

Tags: python, datetime

I need to compare two dates in a server with python on every row of data. I used `datetime` in this case but due to some limitations it will consume a lot of time on big data. I used below code to create a `datetime` object and use in further:

```
first_date = datetime.strptime(line_content[3], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000000Z') 
second_date = datetime.strptime(line_content[4].strip(), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000000Z')
```

I want to compare dates with their string and don't use `datetime`, if I do so there would be a lot of time cost reduction in these kind of data. so use below tests in this regards in python:

```
>>> "2016-07-28T06:04:12.000000Z" < "2016-04-28T06:04:13.000000Z"
False
>>> "2016-07-28T06:04:12.000000Z" < "2016-07-28T06:04:13.000000Z"
True
>>>
>>> "2016-07-28T06:04:12.000000Z" < "2016-07-28T06:04:11.000000Z"
False
>>> "2016-07-28T06:04:12.000000Z" < "2016-07-28T06:04:12.000000Z"
False
>>> "2016-07-28T06:04:12.000000Z" < "2016-07-28T07:04:12.000000Z"
True
>>> "2016-07-28T06:04:12.000000Z" < "2016-07-28T06:04:12.000000Z"
False
>>>
>>> "2016-07-28T06:04:12.000000Z" < "2016-07-26T06:04:12.000000Z"
False
>>> "2016-07-28T06:04:12.000000Z" < "2016-07-29T06:04:12.000000Z"
True
>>> "2016-07-28T06:04:12.000000Z" < "2016-07-28T06:04:12.000000Z"
False
>>>
```

Is this a good way to compare date. I mean can you show me an example that this code won't work?

Comment: It's neither a good nor a working way. Python compares strings lexicographically. Constructing a `datetime` object should not be a performance bottle neck. Are you sure that this is the cause of the issue?

Comment: @DeepSpace but if the dates are all formatted the same way, isn't it the same?

Comment: @DeepSpace: so an obvious not-working example would not have the zero padding. Can you point out when `strptime` will do so?

Comment: Provided that the times are all already localized, and *all* look *exactly* as you're showing (all have leading zeros, none have timezone offsets, etc), then comparing the strings will be the same as comparing two `datetimes` created by parsing these strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - date parsing with Python is pretty slow because dates and times are [complex things](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2725015). According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14163523/2550354) stackoverflow thread, regex might be faster for parsing.

I would think again if you really need to parse the strings, since it looks like your data is clean and have the same format in your case it might work.

Things to keep in mind before going with this approach:

- Do you know the format of your string?
- Does it really goes from year>month>day>hour>minute>sec>etc
- Does all of your data has the same format?
- All of your data is in the same timezone?